# Compile Time HashMap in Zig

Tags: hashmap, zig

Take for example the Rust library `lazy_static`'s [example](https://docs.rs/lazy_static/latest/lazy_static/):

```rust
use lazy_static::lazy_static;
use std::collections::HashMap;

lazy_static! {
    static ref HASHMAP: HashMap<u32, &'static str> = {
        let mut m = HashMap::new();
        m.insert(0, "foo");
        m.insert(1, "bar");
        m.insert(2, "baz");
        m
    };
    static ref COUNT: usize = HASHMAP.len();
    static ref NUMBER: u32 = times_two(21);
}
```

How might this be done in Zig?

I have tried this which is the only thing that makes sense to me:

```
const std = @import("std");

pub fn main() void {
    comptime var h = std.StringHashMap(i32).init(std.testing.allocator);
    h.put("hi", 5) catch {};
    std.debug.print("{}", .{h});
}
```

but this segfaults.

Is it even possible to do this in Zig?

Comment: In the future, it will eventually be possible to create a normal StringHashMap at comptime using a comptime allocator, but in the current version of zig this would be extremely slow and crashes the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

It seems (thanks to this [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Zig/comments/krnuac/is_it_possible_to_create_hash_maps_at_compile_time/)) that this is implemented in the [standard library](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/blob/master/lib/std/comptime_string_map.zig)

and can be used via `std.ComptimeStringMap`

This however does not seem to support any dynamic insertion as there is no `insert` method.